# Dividing a Polygon by Multiple Lines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, polygon, computational-geometry

I have a polygon, as well as a series of lines to cut across it. The polygon is defined by a list of vector points, as are the lines. I have a function Split() that can split any one polygon by one line which returns the polygons created by the split. If no polygons were created, the function returns null.

However, I am trying to figure out an algorithm to split this large polygon by a series of lines, and am trying to figure out how to do this. What I am working with is shown below.

[image]

My current solution is the following:

```
    public static List<List<Vector2>> SliceMany(List<List<Vector2>> ps, Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    List<List<Vector2>> result = new List<List<Vector2>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < ps.Count; i++)
    {
        List<List<Vector2>> sliced = Slice(ps[i], a, b);
        if(sliced != null)
        {
            if (sliced.Count > 1)
            {
                result.AddRange(sliced);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(ps[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, this has multiple issues, including:

- It is incredibly slow and unscalable
- It produces a great number of "waste polygons", ie polygons that have already been split into smaller polygons and are therefore no longer useful

Any suggestions would be helpful. If it helps, this is made using Unity, and I also have a function that can detect overlapping polygons, though I've yet to find a way to effectively leverage it. My desired solution is only the final polygons that have been completely split, and none of the former polygons.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you *triangulate* the polygon, partition it into triangles. There is code all over the web, in many different languages, for this task.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I'm sorry, I'm not sure how this would help. I'm looking to split the polygon in a very specific way rather than just make it small

Comment: Apologies, I did not understand your problem. I guess your problem is that you have a crooked polygonal path that partitions your polygon? I guess that's what you mean by "a series of lines." If instead you literally mean split over and over, each time with an infinite line, then you could use your Split(). It might help if you explained what are the red lines, what is the blue corridor.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Oh, I see what you meant. Yes, the red lines are what I want to divide by, the white area is my polygons, and the blue line is a river. There are two polygons, representing two islands divided by a river. I'm looking to split the white by the red.

Comment: Some of the red lines appear curved. Presumably they are polygonal, but with many edges so they look curved. Unless you have constraints on the shape of the red lines, and the shape of the white polygons, I don't see an easy approach. You would need to compute the intersections between a red line and the boundary of a white region.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem that I mentioned in this post, yet another problem remains (slicing the plane by curves). I'll post the answer I came up with for my original problem here.

```
List<List<Vector2>> result = new List<List<Vector2>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < ps.Count; i++)
    {
        List<List<Vector2>> sliced = Slice(ps[i], line);
        if(sliced != null)
        {
            if (sliced.Count > 1)
            {
                result.AddRange(sliced);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(ps[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(ps[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).